# Localnear root account seed phrase

Tags: nearprotocol

For developing on localnear, contracts and sub-accounts need to be deployed and created programmatically

The localnear deployment script does output the test.near public and private key, however, this workflow is different than the typical seed-phrase driven workflow, and it's also helpful to login to the wallet and see the root account's current state

Is the seed phrase for the root account (i.e. test.near) documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

There is now a static account and details are logged in the [Github Readme](https://github.com/kurtosis-tech/near-kurtosis-module)

It doesn't yet document the seed phrase, but the private key is there